# Alternatives to persist millions of tensors of different shapes?

Tags: io, pytorch

I would like to store thousands to millions of tensors with different shapes to disk. The goal is to use them as a time series dataset. The dataset will probably not fit into memory and I will have to load samples or ranges of samples from disk.

What are some good alternatives to accomplish this and their trade-offs in terms of:

- Compression options
- Reads and writes overhead
- Flexibility (does it allow storing heterogeneous shapes and associated tensor metadata?)
- Ease of use in the code (library API)
- Ease of setting up (does it require a server or another process running?)

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to save anything in disk is by using pickle:

```
import pickle
import torch

a = torch.rand(3,4,5)

# save
with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(a, handle)

# open
with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    b = pickle.load(handle)
```

You can also save things with pytorch directly, but that is just a pytorch wrapper around pikle.

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
torch.save(x, 'tensor.pt')
```

If you want to save multiple tensors in one file, you can wrap them in a dictionary:

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
a = torch.rand(2,3,4,5)
b = torch.zeros(37)
torch.save({"a": a, "b":b, "x", x}, 'tensors.pt')
```

Comment: I think pickling this many tensors will take up too much memory.

Comment: You can use npz from numpy, it compresses the data. But unless you use some dedicated format for saving and loading data (such as png for images or mp3 for sound), I don't know if there is much more you can do

Answer (score 1):

h5py lets you save lots of tensors into the same file, and you don't have to be able to fit the entire file contents into memory. h5py will store tensors directly to disk, and you can load tensors you want when you want. It allows slicing of these tensors, at load and save time, which works in a similar way, i.e. no need to load entire tensor into memory, in order to load a slice of it, or in order to save a slice of it.